# Shiny server: what does "session" do? Difference of server with and without "session"

Tags: r, session, shiny, server

I'm pretty new to Shiny, and not an R expert.

What is the difference between having "session" in the server function or not?
Maybe a simple example helps too

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This information is well documented by the creators of Shiny. [Shiny session](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/session.html)